# Ajuda a diminuir o tamanho dos scripts php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, revisão-de-código

Como poderia melhorar o script abaixo,seria possivel fazer algo com as consultas ou coisa sim, pois faz tudo que preciso, mais ficou um tanto bagunçado e grande, o que poderia fazer?

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";

if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['usu_login'])) {
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: ../../logout.php"); exit;
}

ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

session_start();  
    $var_usu       = $_SESSION['usu_id'];
    $var_login     = $_SESSION['usu_login'];  
    $var_nome      = $_SESSION['usu_nome']; 
    $var_nivel     = $_SESSION['usu_nivel_checklist'];
    $var_loja      = $_SESSION['usu_loja_id'];
    $var_quest     = $_SESSION['quest'];
    $var_quest_id  = $_SESSION['quest_id'];
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">
<head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title><?php echo $emp_desc ; ?></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
<center>
  <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading"><?php echo $emp_desc ; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
<?php
//CONSULTA PARA LISTAR AS SUB_AREAS
try {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT
                            id_area       AS AREA, 
                            area_desc     AS DESC_AREA,
                            id_sub_area   AS SUB_AREA,
                            sub_area_nome AS DESC_SUB_AREA
                             FROM relacaoset     AS rs
                                  INNER JOIN area     AS ar ON rs.id_area     = ar.area_id
                                  INNER JOIN sub_area AS sb ON rs.id_sub_area = sb.sub_area_cod
                                     WHERE id_area = :var_nivel');
  $stmt->execute(array('var_nivel' => $var_nivel));

  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

  if ( count($result) ) { 
    foreach($result as $row) {

        $var_area          = $row["AREA"];
        $var_desc_area     = $row["DESC_AREA"];
        $var_sub_area      = $row["SUB_AREA"];
        $var_desc_sub_area = $row["DESC_SUB_AREA"];
//CONSULTA PARA CONTAR AS RESPOSTAS
  $q_respostas  = $conn->query("SELECT 
                                COUNT(resp_pergunta_id)  AS TOTAL  
                                  FROM respostas 
                                      WHERE 
                                            resp_loja         ='$var_loja'
                                        AND resp_area        <>'$var_area'
                                        AND resp_questionario ='$var_quest_id'");
                  while ($row = $q_respostas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $var_total_resposta  = $row["TOTAL"];
                       }

//CONSULTA PARA CONTAR AS PERGUNTAS
$q_count_geral = $conn->query("SELECT 
                              COUNT(rp.id)  AS TOTAL_PERG      
                                  FROM 
                                    relacaoperg AS rp 
                                      INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
                                      INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
                                      INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
                                            WHERE 
                                      a.area_id > '1'");
                                        while ($row = $q_count_geral->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                           $var_totalgeral  = $row["TOTAL_PERG"];
                                                }



    }   
$total_perg_area2 = $conn->query("SELECT 
                              COUNT(rp.id)  AS TOTAL_PERG      
                                  FROM 
                                    relacaoperg AS rp 
                                      INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
                                      INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
                                      INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
                                            WHERE 
                                      a.area_id = '2'");
                                        while ($row = $total_perg_area2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                           $var_total_perg_area2  = $row["TOTAL_PERG"];
                                                }
$total_perg_area3 = $conn->query("SELECT 
                              COUNT(rp.id)  AS TOTAL_PERG      
                                  FROM 
                                    relacaoperg AS rp 
                                      INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
                                      INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
                                      INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
                                            WHERE 
                                      a.area_id = '3'");
                                        while ($row = $total_perg_area3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                           $var_total_perg_area3  = $row["TOTAL_PERG"];
                                                }
$total_perg_area4 = $conn->query("SELECT 
                              COUNT(rp.id)  AS TOTAL_PERG      
                                  FROM 
                                    relacaoperg AS rp 
                                      INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
                                      INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
                                      INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
                                            WHERE 
                                      a.area_id = '4'");
                                        while ($row = $total_perg_area4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                           $var_total_perg_area4  = $row["TOTAL_PERG"];
                                                }
$total_perg_area5 = $conn->query("SELECT 
                              COUNT(rp.id)  AS TOTAL_PERG      
                                  FROM 
                                    relacaoperg AS rp 
                                      INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
                                      INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
                                      INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
                                            WHERE 
                                      a.area_id ='5'");
                                        while ($row = $total_perg_area5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                           $var_total_perg_area5  = $row["TOTAL_PERG"];
                                                }
$total_perg_area6 = $conn->query("SELECT 
                              COUNT(rp.id)  AS TOTAL_PERG      
                                  FROM 
                                    relacaoperg AS rp 
                                      INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
                                      INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
                                      INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
                                            WHERE 
                                      a.area_id = '6'");
                                        while ($row = $total_perg_area6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                           $var_total_perg_area6  = $row["TOTAL_PERG"];
                                                }
$total_perg_area7 = $conn->query("SELECT 
                              COUNT(rp.id)  AS TOTAL_PERG      
                                  FROM 
                                    relacaoperg AS rp 
                                      INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
                                      INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
                                      INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
                                            WHERE 
                                      a.area_id = '7'");
                                        while ($row = $total_perg_area7->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                           $var_total_perg_area7  = $row["TOTAL_PERG"];
                                                }
//CONSULTA PARA CONTAR AS RESPOSTAS POR SETORES
  $count_area2  = $conn->query("SELECT 
                                COUNT(resp_pergunta_id)  AS TOTAL  
                                  FROM respostas 
                                      WHERE 
                                            resp_loja         ='$var_loja'
                                        AND resp_area         ='2'
                                        AND resp_questionario ='$var_quest_id'");
                  while ($row = $count_area2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $var_area2  = $row["TOTAL"];
                       }
  $count_area3  = $conn->query("SELECT 
                                COUNT(resp_pergunta_id)  AS TOTAL  
                                  FROM respostas 
                                      WHERE 
                                            resp_loja         ='$var_loja'
                                        AND resp_area         ='3'
                                        AND resp_questionario ='$var_quest_id'");
                  while ($row = $count_area3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $var_area3  = $row["TOTAL"];
                       }
  $count_area4  = $conn->query("SELECT 
                                COUNT(resp_pergunta_id)  AS TOTAL  
                                  FROM respostas 
                                      WHERE 
                                            resp_loja         ='$var_loja'
                                        AND resp_area         ='4'
                                        AND resp_questionario ='$var_quest_id'");
                  while ($row = $count_area4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $var_area4  = $row["TOTAL"];
                       }
  $count_area5  = $conn->query("SELECT 
                                COUNT(resp_pergunta_id)  AS TOTAL  
                                  FROM respostas 
                                      WHERE 
                                            resp_loja         ='$var_loja'
                                        AND resp_area         ='5'
                                        AND resp_questionario ='$var_quest_id'");
                  while ($row = $count_area5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $var_area5  = $row["TOTAL"];
                       }
$count_area6  = $conn->query("SELECT 
                                COUNT(resp_pergunta_id)  AS TOTAL  
                                  FROM respostas 
                                      WHERE 
                                            resp_loja         ='$var_loja'
                                        AND resp_area         ='6'
                                        AND resp_questionario ='$var_quest_id'");
                  while ($row = $count_area6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $var_area6  = $row["TOTAL"];
                       }
$count_area7  = $conn->query("SELECT 
                                COUNT(resp_pergunta_id)  AS TOTAL  
                                  FROM respostas 
                                      WHERE 
                                            resp_loja         ='$var_loja'
                                        AND resp_area         ='7'
                                        AND resp_questionario ='$var_quest_id'");
                  while ($row = $count_area7->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $var_area7  = $row["TOTAL"];
                       }


  $total_respostas = $var_area2 +
                     $var_area3 +
                     $var_area4 +
                     $var_area5 +
                     $var_area6 +
                     $var_area7;

$diferença = $var_totalgeral - $total_respostas; 


if ($var_total_resposta >= $var_totalgeral){
echo"<div class='jumbotron'>
  <h4>OLÁ,</h4>
  <p>TODOS OS SETORES RESPONDERAM SUAS PERGUNTAS, POR FAVOR CLICAR NO BOTÃO ABAIXO PARA RESPONDER AS PERGUNTAS.
  <p><a href='principal.php?sub_area_id=$var_sub_area&area_id=$var_area&desc_sub_area=$var_desc_sub_area&desc_area=$var_desc_area' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'>RESPONDER</a></p>
</div>";
 }else{

echo"<table class='table table-striped table-hover'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor='#00FF00'><font color='000000'>TOTAL PERGUNTAS: $var_totalgeral  </font></th>
      <th bgcolor='#00FF00'><font color='000000'>TOTAL RESPOSTAS: $total_respostas </font></th>
      <th bgcolor='#FF0000'><font color='000000'>DIFERENÇA: $diferença             </font></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>SETOR</th>
      <th>TOTAL PERGUNTAS</th>
      <th>TOTAL RESPOSTAS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>area2</td>
      <td>$var_total_perg_area2</td>
      <td>$var_area2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>area3</td>
      <td>$var_total_perg_area3</td>
      <td>$var_area3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>area4</td>
      <td>$var_total_perg_area4</td>
      <td>$var_area4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>area5</td>
      <td>$var_total_perg_area5</td>
      <td>$var_area5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>area6</td>
      <td>$var_total_perg_area6</td>
      <td>$var_area6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>area7</td>
      <td>$var_total_perg_area7</td>
      <td>$var_area7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>";


 }


  } else {
      echo"<center><b>NENHUM SETOR SELECIONADO</b><center>";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
        echo"<a href='logout.php' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span> SAIR</a><br>";



 ?>






  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: não entendi os -2, na  minha concepção a pergunta esta clara e estou precisando de uma dica, isso foge das regras da comunidade?

Comment: A maioria dessas consulta parece a mesma exceto pelo `a.area_id` mudar, dar um `group by` não resolveria isso? Outra dica quando o mesmo processo se repetir vc jogar ele dentro de uma função, e peça como argumento os elementos que variam.

Comment: Obrigado @rray já estou fazendo, terminando posto a finalização.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisando suas `querys` identifiquei que tem 7 delas que tem o mesmo objetivo, que é trazer a quantidade de respostas por área. Então sugiro que você retorne todas de uma única vez, assim você pode reduzir o esforço a apenas uma execução que retornará todos os dados necessários deste somatório.

```
SELECT resp_loja,
       SUM(CASE WHEN resp_area = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN resp_area = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN resp_area = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN resp_area = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN resp_area = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area5,
       SUM(CASE WHEN resp_area = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area6,
       SUM(CASE WHEN resp_area = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area7,
       COUNT(resp_pergunta_id) as total
  FROM respostas
 GROUP BY resp_loja
```

No caso acima, o `SUM` tem um `CASE` para garantir que apenas a área em questão terá o resultado (que no caso é 1) somado. Garantimos assim o funcionamento com o uso semelhante ao `COUNT` porém separado por área.

Seguindo o mesmo exemplo, segue a `query` para contar as perguntas:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN area_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN area_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN area_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN area_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN area_id = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area5,
       SUM(CASE WHEN area_id = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area6,
       SUM(CASE WHEN area_id = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS area7,
       COUNT(id) as total
  FROM relacaoperg
```

O importante é que retornará apenas uma linha, portanto você pode pegar o total de acordo com a área apenas pelo nome da coluna.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você já pensou em utilizar MVC?

**O que é MVC?**

> MVC significa Model – View – Controller (Modelo – Visão – Controlador)
>   e é um modelo da arquitetura de software que tem a **função de separar**
>   front-end (que o usuário vê) do back-end (que é o motor da aplicação).

Este link é a parte 3 de um ótimo tutorial de mvc em php:

[Conexão PDO e gerencia dados da base de dados](https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2014/09/mvc-em-php-parte-3/)

Você também pode utilizar alguma framework, recomendo a Yii, é o item 7 deste link:

[13 PHP Frameworks](http://mashable.com/2014/04/04/php-frameworks-build-applications/#zU_MsU1xPkqc)

Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte!

Comment: @Diego se eu vou colar o exemplo fornecido pelo próprio tutorial (resumidamente) seria suficiente? Como sou nova não posso colocar mais links, mas a fonte do "o que é mcv?" é o mesmo link do tutorial (parte 1). Obrigada por me ajudar a melhorar.

Comment: Legal a sua tentativa de ajudar, mas recomendar o uso do MVC ou de frameworks não vai resolver o problema dele. Como é novo na comunidade recomendo a leitura da [tour] e [como responder](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) se tiver mais alguma dúvida só perguntar.

Comment: A pergunta dele é: Como poderia melhorar o script abaixo (..)? O código funciona mas falta organização... Indicar o uso de MVC ou de uma framework não é valido? @rray Te faço a mesma pergunta que fiz acima: se eu vou colar o exemplo fornecido pelo próprio tutorial (resumidamente) seria suficiente? Obrigada por me ajudar a melhorar. =)

Comment: Acho que fica fora de contexto, não olhei o código detalhadamente mas deixei uma [sugestão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164072/ajuda-a-diminuir-o-tamanho-dos-scripts-php-mysql#comment337575_164072) que tenta atacar o problema diretamente, veja que tem um 'duplicação' de consultas.

Comment: sim, tem muita coisa repetida... fazer uma função já ajudaria a melhorar